# What can be said about this limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations

Suppose that $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_k, z_1, ..., z_k\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|z_1| = |z_2| = \cdots = |z_k|$.
For $k > 1$, what can be said about the limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\alpha_1z_1^{n+1} + ... + \alpha_kz_k^{n+1}}{\alpha_1 z_1^n + ... + \alpha_kz_k^n}$$

Comment: that it's $\leq |z_1|$ I believe

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak Explain?  If $n = 2$ then there are cases in which this limit does not converge.

Comment: I agree, but when if and when it does it will remain smaller than the common module of zi.

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak Please reply with a proof.

Comment: I would suggest looking at examples - the first that comes to mind is $z_m$ all roots of unity of order $k$ and $\alpha_m=1$ (except a small indent at say $\alpha_1=1+\epsilon$ to avoid singularities. So without restrictions, I doubt that much can be said at least as stated.